# Can't solve problem with android plugin and gradle in flutter

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I create a new project. Then have this problem:

The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Build file 'C:\wolk\flutter\calcul\android\app\build.gradle' line: 2
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

I tried first updating jdk, then reinstalling jdk and Android studio, changing the information in build.gradle, nothing helps